# Getting an android app with geofence to properly send a notification to Android Auto

Tags: android, kotlin, android-auto

I have a generally well working application built in kotlin which has a geofence listener service which sends notifications to both the mobile device and the Android Auto unit when a geofence is entered.

My issue is that when I click the android auto notification in the head unit, which I want to open my Android Auto application, I get an error in Android Auto, "Android Auto has encountered an unexpected error" and "Failed to combine to componentinfo".

My understanding is possibly that I am passing the wrong context in the "CarPendingIntent", as this should be the "Auto" app context instead of the "Application Context".

My problem is I don't know how to get the "Auto Context" as the auto app is not running and the auto service is not running when the geofence receiver is alerted.

I have a minimized version of this mobile app and auto app which illustrates the issue here
https://github.com/coinzdude/SimpleAutoNotification

This app will simply push a notification to mobile and the auto head unit, and if you click the head unit notification the error occurs, instead of opening the head unit app.

```
CarAppExtender.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentIntent(
                        CarPendingIntent.getCarApp(
                            context.applicationContext, 0,
                            Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setComponent(
                                ComponentName(
                                    context.applicationContext,
                                    SGService::class.java
                                )
                            ), 0
                        )
                    )
                    .setChannelId(context.getString(R.string.garage_notification))
                    .build()
```

I am guessing that what I need to do is get my geofence listener service to somehow notify the ".SGService" which is my car app's service and then that service can get the proper context and then clicking the notification would properly open my auto app (the screen).

If so, how can I send an intent into the auto application?  When my geofence listener receives a message, there's no car app service running, so it has not yet had a chance to set up a listener.

I have not published the full IOT garage door application to github as I'm doing a bit of housecleaning on the code, but I would publish that as well if it helps to see what I'm trying to do.

An interesting thing is that if I manually start the head unit application, and then click the head unit notification, my head unit application opens without error.  I just cannot get the notification to *initially* open the head unit app.

I also logged this with Google, but I did not find the response too helpful in my case. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/273624977

Comment: Hi, I am trying to send a notification from my mobile app to the auto app but I didn't succeed. I am guessing it's because of context issues, can you please share more on what you've achieved ? I don't seem to find good documentation on the subject as well.

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT and a bunch of stumbling got this working. I landed here.

I have no idea why this works.

```
<service
    android:name=".SGService"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.lusion.sgauto.LAUNCH" />
        <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService" />
        <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.IOT" />
    </intent-filter> </service>
```

add a receiver directly to the class and register it on create, specifically that this is "LocalBroadcastManager"

```
class SGService : CarAppService() {
    private var garageUpdateThread: Thread? = null

    private val mMessageReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val message = intent.getStringExtra("message")
            Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: $message" ) //            onCreateSession()
            // handle the message
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " )
        super.onCreate()
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, IntentFilter("com.lusion.sgauto.SGService"))
    }
```

don't forget ondestroy

> ```
> override fun onDestroy() {
>     Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy")
>     try {
>         stopMonitoring()
>         unregisterReceiver(uiMessageBroadcastReceiver)
>         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
>
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to report back. I have done nothing and this just "started working", so thanks for telling me this can't be done @google and then still seemingly doing something about it. :-)